# how to print data from mysql into a pdf file. Header and footer are printing but data from mysql is not printing

Tags: php, html

I am trying to generate a pdf form through below given script. When I generate the pdf file it only printing header and footer. **I am unable to print values from database.** `db.php` and `fpdf.php` are correct. Output is attached Please help.
[image]

```
<?php

    include "includes/db.php";

    require('includes/fpdf/fpdf.php');

    class PDF extends FPDF
    {
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
    // Logo
    $this->Image('assets/img/find_user.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(60,10,'Shekhat test',0,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(8);

    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',7);

    $this->Cell(220,10,'Pune, Maharashtra',0,0,'C');


    $this->Ln(30);

    $this->SetDrawColor(188,188,188);
    $this->Line(0,45,350,45);

    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
    }



    // Instanciation of inherited class
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);


    if(isset($_GET['print_slider'])){ 

        $get_id = $_GET['print_slider'];


    $result="SELECT * FROM homeslider WHERE banner_id='$get_id'";
    //$result="SELECT * FROM homeslider";

    $rows = mysqli_query($con, $result); 


    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rows, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Banner id:' ,$row['banner_id']); 
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Banner Title:' ,$row['banner_title']);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Banner Image:' ,$row['banner_image']);

        }

    }
    $pdf->Output();

    ?>
```

Comment: Did you try `print_r($row)` just to check whether there is some data out there to be included into the document?

Comment: Thanks @AntonSamsonov, I have tried `print_r($row)` and thats showing me an error as              `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects...`

Comment: Do you mean that `print_r()` results in error, or you got a delight about previous error after inspecting its output? In any case, please share the details.

Comment: I am getting this output with error `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) 
`

Comment: Why do you consider this an error? With *num_rows=1* and *field_count=3* it appears to have just the data you need: a single row consisting of three fields. Therefore, just `print_r($row['banner_id']);`, etc. to be sure those fields are not empty strings.

Comment: ya right @AntonSamsonov.... but values are not printing on pdf file ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you call the `Cell` method:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Banner id:' , $row['banner_id']);
```

you need to replace the comma with a period..!

So this will work:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Banner id:' . $row['banner_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks @BizzyBob's, now it's working fine with your answer.... How to print image ? Current code printing image name.